# Xcode 10.2.1 Performance Issues

Tags: xcode, xcode10, xcode10.2

I have been using Xcode 10.2.1 since it came out and been having a pretty consistent performance issue. If I have Xcode open for a while it get's increasingly slow to the point that it's nearly unusable. Even clicking on controls in interface builder has a 2-5 second lag. The issue seems to resolve itself after restarting Xcode, but it's getting pretty annoying working with a laggy Xcode. I've also noticed that previously opened files are sequentially closed out of the main window (~5 per second) as Xcode quits like they had been open the whole time. It's very odd. Anyone have any idea what's going on or how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same issues with lag, scrolling a page or clicking on anything will often bring up the spinning pizza wheel.

Comment: Same issue on 10.3 running 2011 iMac